# Convert regular expression to FA?

Tags: regular-languages, finite-automata, regular-expressions

I am trying to solve a practice problem from my textbook which is to draw an FA from this language: L(ab* a*) U L((ab)*ba)

I need help to draw the second part L((ab)*ba). I know the shortest string is ba, then it is abba, ababba, abababba, etc.

I started off with this to show the shortest string:
[image: FA]

However, now I need to add the (ab)* part in the front of this which I am unsure how to approach this.

Any help would be great, and sorry if this seems obvious to some of you... I just don't see it right now!

EDIT: If it were (a*)ba I know how I would approach it, but the (ab)* is confusing me.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thompson%27s_construction

Comment: The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Comment: There are standard constructions for this, which can be found in any textbook or set of lecture notes on the subject. I suggest you look at the construction and ask again if you have a more specific question.

Answer (score 0):

> $L = (ab)^*ba$

Divide $L$ into two part for easy construct the FA as

1. $(ab)^*$
2. $ba$

Draw 1 and 2, end all undesired path to a dead state.

[image]

Comment: Almost, but you need to reverse the direction of the two leftmost arrows.

Comment: Sorry, mistake while drawing. [FA diagram updated with correct answer]